# How to use findById in indexAction side by findAll()?

Tags: symfony

im trying to edit my indexAction function, i want to findByOne for user

```
public function indexAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $leaveRequests = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:LeaveRequest')->findAll();
    } else {
        $leaveRequests = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:LeaveRequest')->findOneBy(['id‌​' => $id]);
    }

    return $this->render('leaverequest/index.html.twig', array(
        'leaveRequests' => $leaveRequests,
    ));
}
```

And I get the following error

> Notice: Undefined variable: id

I've looked through entity, but haven't found anything.
here is my entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * LeaveRequest
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="leave_request")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\LeaveRequestRepository")
 */
class LeaveRequest
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="date")
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="date")
     */
    private $endDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="leaveRequests")
     *
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User;
     */
    protected $user;


    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return LeaveRequest
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set startDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startDate
     *
     * @return LeaveRequest
     */
    public function setStartDate($startDate)
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartDate()
    {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set endDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endDate
     *
     * @return LeaveRequest
     */
    public function setEndDate($endDate)
    {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEndDate()
    {
        return $this->endDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return LeaveRequest
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return LeaveRequest
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set userId
     *
     * @param integer $userId
     *
     * @return LeaveRequest
     */
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * Is the given User the author of this Post?
     *
     * @param User|null $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isUser(User $user = null)
    {
        return $user && $user->getId() == $this->getUserId();
    }
}
```

Edit : Adding missing parts from entity as codes. Thanks in advance to anyone adds an answer for this.

Comment: You have `findById` in your code, shouldn't it be `findOne`? Of course it will currently fail, you are basically saying "find me one entity by specific id" - and the system wants to know, what that id is

Comment: yes, i acctually changed that now for findOneBy(['id' => $id]), still not working tho

Comment: Not working means what? If you receive an error message, please edit it in the question (and when you're doing that, you can update the code to reflect the one you are currently using)

Comment: right, so here is code which im using currently       public function indexAction()
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $leaveRequests = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:LeaveRequest')->findAll();
        } else {
            $leaveRequests = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:LeaveRequest')->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
        }
        return $this->render('leaverequest/index.html.twig', array(
            'leaveRequests' => $leaveRequests,
        ));
        
    }

Comment: and its not error really, but notice 
"Notice: Undefined variable: id",

Comment: The message is quite clear, `$id` is not defined, but you still try to use it. Can you elaborate (in text & as edit in the question itself), what exactly it is you are trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to separate an admin access from user access to all users, so user can see only own data, i get a message, but i dont know how i can defined $id, cos symfony dosen't accept any definition, so i have tried to fetch that from doctrine but still throwing error

Comment: So this id value should be the id of the connected user and not the one of the  LeaveRequest entity. Can you edit your question to provide the code of the LeaveRequest entity.

Comment: please start accepting answers in case the problem is solved, this will help others with similar problems

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use an undefined variable (like the notice said)

Here an example of what you can do :

```
public function indexAction() {
    $user   = $this->getUser();
    $userId = $user->getId();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $leaveRequests = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:LeaveRequest')->findAll();
    } else {
        // I admit that in your LeaveRequest entity you have a relation with your User Entity which name is 'userId'
        $leaveRequests = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:LeaveRequest')->findOneBy(['userId​' => $userId]);
    }

    return $this->render('leaverequest/index.html.twig', array(
        'leaveRequests' => $leaveRequests,
    ));
}
```

Regards

Comment: thanks, i have done that also before and now i have this message Unrecognized field: userId​

Comment: Because I say you must replace 'userId' with your mapped field.
Check your Entity to see wich field has a relation with your User Entity

Comment: hmmmm, right, so i have edit this action how you told me and now is almost fine, but on the page there is no data about the user anyway, just the empty table, any idea what am i doing wrong?